# jQuery: A shortcut to create a div container after a cue word

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, traversal

I'm creating a shortcut for a blog theme where I want to generate a div container around elements after using a cue word. For example, my blog entry would like this:

```
<div class="entry">

<p>First Paragraph</p>

<p>[box]</p>

<p>Second Paragraph</p>

<p>Third Paragraph</p>

</div> <!-- .entry -->
```

I'm hoping with some jQuery magic it could turn into this:

```
<div class="entry">

<p>First Paragraph</p>

<div class="box">

<p>Second Paragraph</p>

<p>Third Paragraph</p>

</div> <!-- .box -->

</div> <!-- .entry -->
```

One more rule: When I create a container box, I know I will always generate it before the closing div.entry. I'm hoping this restriction will make it easier to write the rules for jQuery. For example, I will never want the markup to look like this where there is content proceeding the div.box container:

```
<!-- I will never mark it up this way -->

<div class="entry">

<p>First Paragraph</p>

<div class="box">

<p>Second Paragraph</p>

</div> <!-- .box -->

<p>Third paragraph</p>

</div> <!-- .entry -->
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm also currently trying to rewrite some of the markup to make the rules even easier than this: I'm figuring out .after() to completely rewrite the [box] string so that it closes a div container, and opens a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is the [jQuery :contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector.
With it you could do things like this (note: it matches any paragraph that has [box] in its HTML and maybe you need to escape the brackets):

```
$("p:contains('[box]')").wrap($('<div>').addClass('box'));
```

And btw. accepting answers and proving that you already put effort in your
problem will make it much more likely to get a helpful reply.

Comment: Noted and thanks for the :contains tip! I was really stuck with my first line of code, so thought it best to simply start fresh with defining the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like this:

```
$("div.entry").append(
  $("<div>").addClass("box").append("p:contains([box])+*");
);
$("p:contains([box])").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

[**See an example of the following here.**](http://www.jsfiddle.net/wWCHQ/)

You can find the [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) of the [box] paragraph and then [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) the `<p>` after using [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) to get all the parapgraphs following it:

```
var boxAt;

$('p').each(function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    if ($t.html() === '[box]') {
        boxAt = $t.index();
        $t.remove();
    }
});

$('p:gt(' + (boxAt - 1) + ')').wrapAll('<div class="box">');
```

Comment: I just realized that I need to create a div container preceeding all HTML elements after all to get my floats to work properly. I'm saving this for future use!

Comment: Glad you like, all the thanks I desire for a working solution to your problem is an up-vote if it's not too much trouble.  The more you upvote and accept answers, the more likely people are to help you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help! It helped me also come up with another strategy that worked for me as well:

```
$('.entry p:contains([box])').each( function() {
    $(this).prevAll().wrapAll('<div class="lefty">');
});

$('.entry p:contains([box])').each( function() {
    $(this).nextAll().wrapAll('<div class="righty">');
});
$("p:contains([box])").remove();
```

What this does is create two separate boxes: 1. elements preceding [box], 2. elements proceeding [box]

Comment: Darn, so close! When using prevAll(), the elements are reversed in the div.lefty container. All the elements in process with .nextAll() are appearing in the right forward order. I tried .reverse() like this, but it causes an error: `$('.entry p:contains([box])').each( function() { $(this).prevAll().reverse().wrapAll('<div class="lefty">'); });`